# How Can I get a While loop with an If statement in Java to stop after a certain number of loops?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, break

Below is my code and I would like to know how I can get it to stop after a certain number of loops.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int height_requirement = 50;
while(true) {
    System.out.print("Enter height -> ");
    int height = scanner.nextInt();     
    if (height < height_requirement) {
        System.out.println("You are too short to ride the ride the roller coaster.");
    }
    System.out.println("You can ride the roller coaster");
}
```

Comment: Seems like a `for` loop would be a better fit. Anyway something like, `int counter = 0; while (counter++ < yourLimit) { ....` should work.

Comment: or while (conditionTrue() ) -> and have a condition actually checked instead of while (true)

Comment: For the posted code - is the condition for terminating the loop the "too short" condition?  Based on the lack of an `else` it would suggest you want to `break` the loop there.  This would contradict your "number of loops" requirement though.  Please provide clarity on the exit condition for the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop:

```java
int maxLoops = 5;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)
int height_requirement = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < maxLoops; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter height -> ");
    int height = scanner.nextInt();     
    if (height < height_requirement) {
        System.out.println("You are too short to ride the ride the roller coaster.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You can ride the roller coaster");
    }
}
```

Also there was a small mistake at the very end of the loop.

Comment: Oh, my God! Thank you so much! At first I thought the only difference between your code and mine was the first line of the code, but today after I looked more closely I saw the other differences and I tried it out and it worked! That's great! ~Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Normally there is `for` with index which you can easy control until what number to go.

If you want the solution with `while` try this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int height_requirement = 50;
int count = 5; // give start number
while(count > 0) { // check if count is bigger then 0
    count--; // remove -1 each time. This way while will do 5 iterations
   
    System.out.print("Enter height -> ");
    int height = scanner.nextInt();     
    if (height < height_requirement) {
        System.out.println("You are too short to ride the ride the roller coaster.");
    }
    else // put "You can ride the roller coaster" in else not to be printed every time
    { 
        System.out.println("You can ride the roller coaster");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use break statement to end the while loop alone with a if statement.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int height_requirement = 50;
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter height -> ");
        int height = scanner.nextInt();
        if (height < height_requirement) {
            System.out.println("You are too short to ride the ride the roller coaster.");
            break;        // To break the loop
        } else{
            System.out.println("You can ride the roller coaster");            }

    }
```

Comment: OP asked to stop after a certain number of loops, not after the first one. Why have a loop in the first place if you always exit after the first iteration?